# Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in

Tags: php

I hope you can help me. I have this error in my php code and I cant figure out what do I need to change and where. It is showing that in this line where it in stars.

Here is my code:

```
private function replaceFile($id, $file, $version) {

    global $CFG;
    $source = get_record('procedure_log','procedure_id', $id);
    $destination = $CFG->dataroot . "/procedures/$id/$version/";
    @mkdir($destination, 0777, true);
    $dataobject = new stdClass();
    $dataobject->id = $this->logId;
    $dataobject->file = addslashes($destination . $file['name']);
    **copy(var_dump($source.$file['name'], $destination.$file['name'] ));**
}
```

Comment: You need to learn how to [READ and debug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php) error messages. Everything you needed to solve the problem was in the error message. Somewhere you are trying to use an object as if it was a string maybe $source for instance

Comment: see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032687/php-catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-stdclass-could-not-be-converted-to-s

Answer (score 1):

`$source` is probably object and you can't use it as string (you tried to do it by joining with `$file['name']` string using dot). You should select what you want to add to this string.

Comment: Not sure how they can add __toString() to stdClass

Comment: @Anigel Right, he can't :) But he can specify what he want to add to string.

Comment: I need file from the object $source copy to the $destination file. Sorry, I am new in php. An I am she :D

Comment: @Erika I can't edit previous comment to change that "he" ;) Try to use `$source->file` and in case of problems check what you'll see after writing `var_dump($source);`.

Comment: Thank you Elon. I still learning this bloody php :) Thanks again and dont worry about he :D It is not a problem :D

Comment: @Elon. I am not getting anymore fatal error, just trying to find out why my copy function is not working :) Thanks again :)

Comment: @Erika I think it's because you are using `var_dump` with `copy`. Skip it and its brackets.

Comment: @Erika And now it's ok? ;) BTW. Remove `@` from `mkdir` and check if `$source->file` contains proper folder path (with trailing slash).

Comment: @Elon. I checked, it contains proper folder, just still not making cop. So now Ill create a new procedure and Ill check again. Also I removed @ from mkdir :)

Answer (score 1):

You function `get_record` probably returning the object not a string that your assigning in the variable `$source`. You need to check that what is the value of `$source` variable by echoing it.

And you will get your exact problem.