# PHP Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php

I have made a small multiplication function

```
 <p><?php
 $a= "<?php echo $this->prodDet->v_price?>";
 $b=.26;
 $c=$a*$b;
 echo $c;
 ?>
```

Here the price value is extracted from database of the requiste product and is multiple by fixed .26 variable. Wondering why am getting this errror -

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in
```

I am learning the basics of PHP. can someone suggest how to get it solved please?

Thanks

Comment: When you're writing PHP, bear in mind that you can never nest `<?php ?>` blocks. When you get to `$a="<?php`, you're already inside a `<?php` block from the first line (we've not seen a closing `?>`), so that's where things stop making sense. You're trying to set $a to the string `<?php echo $this->prodDet->v_price?>`, which is valid, but not what you want to do. As a side-effect it's trying to evaluate `$this` as a string because you're using [double-quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't know what you're trying here?

```
$a = "<?php echo $this->prodDet->v_price?>";
```

`$a` looks after the assignment like `<?php echo <the value of $this->prodDet->v_price>?>`. The `<?php` part there is not executed. You surely want to write:

```
$a = $this->prodDet->v_price;
```

And make sure that `$a` is not an object at the end! (what you can check via `var_dump($a);` in the line after the assignment)

Answer (score 3):

`v_price` has been set as a class instance somewhere before these lines of code.  My guess is that happens somewhere in `prodDet`.

So, when you `echo` it, PHP tries to convert to a string and fails.

To see what kind of class it is, try:

```
var_dump($this->prodDet->v_price);
```

That will help you debug.

---

An example is in [PHP: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032687/php-catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-stdclass-could-not-be-converted-to-s?rq=1), where the person accidentally sets a variable to be a class in this line:

```
$procID = $client->start(array("prefix"=>"Genesis"));
```

then they try to echo `$procID` and get the same error.  You can't echo a class because it can't be changed to a string.

---

Also, when you do

```
$a = echo ...
```

`$a` will not be what you expect, since `echo` just prints out to the screen!  It doesn't return the value.  You'll want to remove the `echo` and just set it directly:

```
$a = $this->prodDet->v_price->getSomeValue();
```

Answer (score 3):

I also get same error message which is

[image]

after one hour checking everything i find that i have done some small mistake which is i have use variable sign ($) twice when fetching data.
which is

[image]

After remove one dollar sign it's working fine,it may be help someone:)

Answer (score 0):

With primitive variable and strings, $name = "Charlie";

Objects store many, related things together.  Strings, numbers, booleans, etc are stored as properties of the object.  Properties are accessed with the object operator ("arrow operator") like $person->name = "Charlie";